# Custom UITableViewCell - nothing visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I have `UITableViewCell` class, which contains customLabel and imageView. When I try to load them in my main `UITableViewController`, nothing happens.

Main `UITableViewController` contains:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UserTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.customButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

PFUser *user = [self.members objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.customLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"Name"];

PFFile *userImage = [user objectForKey:@"Image"];
[userImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }
}];
return cell;
```

}

`UserTableViewCell` contains:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    self.customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 165, 30)];
    self.customLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    self.customLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.customLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.customLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.customLabel];

    self.customButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 5, 40, 30)];
    [self.customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logButtonRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.customButton];

    self.imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 1, 50, 50)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView2];

}
return self;
```

}

Have I missed something? I've set Prototype cell identifier to "Cell" and custom class to `UserTableViewCell`(is this required?)

Comment: Share heightForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection , numberOfSectionsInTableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you set up your cell in IB, and, if so, initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: will not be called. If you want to add UI elements to your cell in code, then you should implement initWithCoder instead. Alternatively, you could register your class (in viewDidLoad of your table view controller), and that will cause initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: to be called (the cell in IB would then be superfluous, since the table view will get the cell from your class definition).

```
[self.tableView  registerClass:[UserTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: Than you so much! This worked flawlessly. I went with your alternative method and deleted the prototype cell from IB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alloc and init your cell when its called the first time:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UserTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if(cell == nil)
  {
    // initialize your cell here
    cell = ...
  }

...
```

Comment: I've added `if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UserTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }` but still nothing happens.